# Total reputation mismatch between main and detail page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, profile-page

I was giving answers to some python questions, I generally open one tab for [python](/questions/tagged/python) to check is there any new question asked or not. When I check reputation on that page and my profile details page, its not matched.

On [python](/questions/tagged/python) page its shows `5,316`

[image: python tag general page]

When I click on my profile and check the reputation tab it shows `5,301`

[image: Profile reputation tab]

Then I checked detail of my reputation activity, but there is no `downvote` for any question.

Comment: The user page is cached. Give it a couple of minutes to catch up.

Comment: [Caching. It's always caching.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CjdOP.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

I guess somebody may have accepted your answer so that you got 15 reputation but suddenely that person have removed you answer from accepted answer but incremented data would be there coming from cache so its showing like this..one Refresh can arrange all the things as it would be!

Comment: then it must have some `+/-` reputation. You can check same situation in my profile image where its shows `+15/-15`.